# ApolloServer not respecting faker-js seeding

Tags: typescript, apollo-server, faker.js

Right now I'm using `apollo-server-express` and creating my ApolloServer with `mocks` like so:

```
import { faker } from "@faker-js/faker";

export const mocks = {
  Person: () => ({
    name: faker.name.fullName
  }),
  People: () => ({
    person: () => [...Array(faker.datatype.number({ min: 1, max: 5 }))]
  })
}
```

Then initializing the server:

```
const server = new ApolloServer({
   ...
   mocks,
   mockEntireSchema: false,
   ...
});
```

Problem is, whenever I query my server (e.g. `Query { people { person { name }}}`), I get the same list every time until I reboot my server. It's like rebooting the server is the only way to create a new seed.

Things I've tried:

1. Adding a plugin that calls `faker.seed()` whenever a response is received. This does seem to set a seed, but the mocks don't seem to respect it.
2. Adding a setInterval to call `faker.seed()` every 5 minutes.
3. Passing a `faker` instance to the `mocks` (and turning mocks into a function that takes "faker") and setting the mocks property to the result of the function, then calling `faker.seed()` the same way as 1 and 2 above.
4. Using `casual` instead of `faker-js`, but I get the same result.

Any help here would be greatly appreciated!